# SWT Text block actions outside of the TextField

Tags: java, swt, e4

I have an SWT Text and I want it to have Focus until the User Enters something.

Currently I´m using a FocusListener and check at focusLost Event, if the User has entered something. If not, I throw him back to the Text Field.

I think this is the wrong way as I don´t want anything to happen which I have to reverse then (e.g. if the user focuses another Part, I have to give focus back to the part with the Text and so on)

Does SWT provide me a way of blocking any other action but entering something into the SWT Text?

Like a Listener that gets triggered before the action happens and in which I can prevent the action to happen? Like a VerifyListener for every event type?

Comment: You can use a blocking dialog, no X button and no cancel buton. When user clicks OK, check input and if empty open dialog again.

Comment: AFAIK, `SWT.FocusOut` is the only thing that can be used for a simple `Text` box to achieve this. The suggestion of @Pphoenix would work, however, I would check the content of the text before closing the dialog at all instead of closing it and reopening it again.

Comment: Thanks! Using a dialog could be a solution for me too.